# Running line for Electric Water Heater

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm encountering a situation where I'm installing a Electric Water Heater in basement and there's a existing unused out for 240 (30 Amp) available right in room above.

Unit specifications are to use 12/2 guage with 20 Amp, independent circuit.

Running a new line is bit of work until is must.  Connecting 12 guage to 10 guage with 30 amp is not safe either. Any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: Can you ask a Question? I think you might be able to do something with a minor change , but I don’t see a question that we can answer.

Comment: What make and model is this heater? What make and model is your breaker panel for that matter?

Answer (score 4):

You are *always* allowed to use larger wire than is required.

The breaker must be appropriate for the load.  If you're upsizing wire, ***don't*** upsize the breaker too!

NEC 110.3b requires you install the equipment according to instructions, so if a 20A breaker is called out, a 20A breaker it is!

The instructions call out 12 AWG wire.  Upsizing wire is always OK, so #10 wire is just fine on any part of the wiring run.

-

The only place instructions or labeling can deter a wire size bump is if the terminals are not rated for the larger wire.  Then you simply pigtail a short bit of the specified size wire (e.g. #12) and then splice it to the larger wire (e.g. #10) right there.

There are rules on junction box fill (number of wires) but pigtails are "free" in these rules.

Comment: I have seen suggestions when using larger wire (#10 in this case) for *some* of a run to attach a note near the breaker box that the run is continued in smaller (#12) wire elsewhere.  This discourages somebody  from thinking later "Oh, this is #10, we can upgrade the breaker to 30A"

Comment: Can I use 12 gauge two wire from 240 wire outlet  and replace 30 Amp fuse to 20 Amp in circuit box.

Comment: Yes, "use 12 gauge two wire from 240 wire outlet and replace 30 Amp".

Comment: Thanks guys for your input.  Cant fish wire through basement beams, if need to run expose 2 feet wire out the outlet to reach corner basement opening, what you guys suggest as conduit, MC wire,  PVC or other. Trying to keep it clean as possible. Thanks